# anaconda navigator suddenly stops working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

Suddenly, my anaconda-navigator stops working! I tried to update it by typing in the terminal:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator 
anaconda-navigator
```

but nothing happened.

Then, I tried to install the following packages:

```
pip install chardet
```

and

```
conda install launcher
```

I also tried to delete the following files:

```
rm -rf config.yaml
```

and

```
rm -Rf ~/.continuum ~/.anaconda
```

But nothing happened!

I still get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/anaconda/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 129, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py", line 33, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 32, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 33, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/client_api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.conda_api import CondaAPI
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/conda_api.py", line 33, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.findpip import PIP_LIST_SCRIPT
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/findpip.py", line 22, in <module>
    import pip
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from . import packages
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.modules['pip._vendor.requests.packages.' + mod] = sys.modules["pip._vendor." + mod]
KeyError: 'pip._vendor.chardet.constants'
```

What does this error mean? and what should I do to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for editing the code! @jdehesa

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. To whomever is facing the same problem, after following the steps that I mentioned earlier in my question above, try to install the package:

```
pip install picage
```

since, as far as I understand, the error key that I get "pip._vendor.chardet.constants" is a subpackage from the main package (picage).

and then you can update your pip by typing (note that this step alone might solve the problem):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

At this point you can call your conda by typing:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

and hopefully it will open (it worked with me!).