# Anaconda stopped working after I tried to install a package, but jupyter notebook still works

Tags: bash, pip, anaconda, conda, xeus-cling

(Currently on Mac OSX 10.10.5)

I wanted to install a C/C++ kernel for jupyter notebook so I tried to [install xeus](https://github.com/QuantStack/xeus) by running the following on terminal:

`conda install xeus -c conda-forge`

The command ran successfully until the end when I received an error that said that I needed Anaconda 4. 
I then referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda) to update anaconda and ran:

`conda update -n root conda`

but got the error:

`conda: command not found`

I then went into my .bashrc file and added:

`export PATH="/Users/anna/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`

I then went into my .bash_profile and saw that anaconda was already on there:

```
#added by Anaconda3 4.3.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/anna/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

I then followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491843/anaconda-navigator-suddenly-stops-working) and ran

`pip install picage`

and got the following error:

```
Collecting picage
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/picage/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement picage (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for picage
```

I'm at a loss for what to do next. I also saw that I had a .bash_profile-anaconda.bak, .bash_profile.bak, .bash_profile.pysave and 3 other .bash_profile.save files. I don't know if that helps in diagnosing this problem.

I also can't open the Anaconda GUI, but I can still use jupyter notebook.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you accepted an install that changed your Python version, which breaks Conda. Although I included a suggestion for how to recover in answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54546450/570918), I don't think anyone has gotten it to work. AFAIK, you need to reinstall Anaconda/Miniconda.

Comment: Hi Merv, thanks for your response. I tried your method of pip installing conda, which worked, but doesn't allow me to use the conda command. I will try to reinstall. I just had one other question - if I do uninstall anaconda will jupyter notebook not run anymore until I reinstall?

Comment: it depends on your configuration, but most likely it will not be available after uninstall, since I expect it's part of your Anaconda installation. But first, I wanted to say that I've updated that answer with a new potential strategy for recovery. I'd appreciate it if you would give it a try and let me know if it works. Thanks, and good luck!